# Zero datanodes running in Hadoop 2.6.5 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to input/upload the file to the hdfs hadoop but it's giving me this error

When I run this command I get this : -

hdfs dfs -put A.txt /input/

```
23/11/08 22:19:25 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /input/A.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1559)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:663)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:975)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2036)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2034)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1401)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:399)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1528)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1345)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:587)
put: File /input/A.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

my jps for master  is

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-143:~$ jps
1155 SecondaryNameNode
2044 Jps
957 NameNode
1278 ResourceManager
```

for slave1 and it's the for other slave nodes as well

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-143:~$ jps
1504 DataNode
1625 NodeManager
1786 Jps
```

hdfs dfsadmin -report command

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-143:~$
logout
Connection to slave1 closed.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-143:~$ hdfs dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: NaN%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
```

core-site.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
                <value>hdfs://master:9000/</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
                <value>file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.5/tmp</value>
        </property>

</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.5/dfs/name</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.5/dfs/data</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>3</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml.template file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
                <value>yarn</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.

  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<configuration>
        <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
                <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
                <value>master:8032</value>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
                <value>master:8030</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
                <value>master:8035</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
                <value>master:8033</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
                <value>master:8088</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

hadoop-env.sh file

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Set Hadoop-specific environment variables here.

# The only required environment variable is JAVA_HOME.  All others are
# optional.  When running a distributed configuration it is best to
# set JAVA_HOME in this file, so that it is correctly defined on
# remote nodes.

# The java implementation to use.
#export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.5
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Set Hadoop-specific environment variables here.

# The only required environment variable is JAVA_HOME.  All others are
# optional.  When running a distributed configuration it is best to
# set JAVA_HOME in this file, so that it is correctly defined on
# remote nodes.

# The java implementation to use.
#export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.5

# The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB. Default is 1000.
#export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=
#export HADOOP_NAMENODE_INIT_HEAPSIZE=""

# Extra Java runtime options.  Empty by default.
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

# Command specific options appended to HADOOP_OPTS when specified
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=${HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER:-INFO,RFAS} -Dhdfs.audit.logger=${HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER:-INFO,NullAppender} $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=ERROR,RFAS $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"

export HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=${HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER:-INFO,RFAS} -Dhdfs.audit.logger=${HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER:-INFO,NullAppender} $HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS"

export HADOOP_NFS3_OPTS="$HADOOP_NFS3_OPTS"
export HADOOP_PORTMAP_OPTS="-Xmx512m $HADOOP_PORTMAP_OPTS"

# The following applies to multiple commands (fs, dfs, fsck, distcp etc)
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx512m $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"
#HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS="-XX:-UsePerfData $HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS"

# On secure datanodes, user to run the datanode as after dropping privileges.
# This **MUST** be uncommented to enable secure HDFS if using privileged ports
# to provide authentication of data transfer protocol.  This **MUST NOT** be
# defined if SASL is configured for authentication of data transfer protocol
# using non-privileged ports.
# using non-privileged ports.
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER=${HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER}

# Where log files are stored.  $HADOOP_HOME/logs by default.
#export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/$USER

# Where log files are stored in the secure data environment.
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/${HADOOP_HDFS_USER}

###
# HDFS Mover specific parameters
###
# Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the HDFS Mover.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# export HADOOP_MOVER_OPTS=""

###
# Advanced Users Only!
###

# The directory where pid files are stored. /tmp by default.
# NOTE: this should be set to a directory that can only be written to by
#       the user that will run the hadoop daemons.  Otherwise there is the
#       potential for a symlink attack.
export HADOOP_PID_DIR=${HADOOP_PID_DIR}
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_PID_DIR=${HADOOP_PID_DIR}
# A string representing this instance of hadoop. $USER by default.
export HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=$USER
```

hadoop-ubuntu-namenode-ip-172-31-46-192.log file (relavent part of of it)

```
/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.5/dfs/name/current/edits_0000000000000000553-0000000000000000553
2023-11-11 23:37:49,726 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream: Fast-forwarding stream '/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.5/dfs/name/current/edits_0000000000000000553-0000000000000000553' to transaction ID 1
2023-11-11 23:37:49,727 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Edits file /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.5/dfs/name/current/edits_0000000000000000553-0000000000000000553 of size 1048576 edits # 1 loaded in 0 seconds
2023-11-11 23:37:49,727 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Need to save fs image? true (staleImage=true, haEnabled=false, isRollingUpgrade=false)
2023-11-11 23:37:49,727 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Save namespace ...
2023-11-11 23:37:49,735 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf: Saving image file /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.5/dfs/name/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000553 using no compression
2023-11-11 23:37:49,824 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf: Image file /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.5/dfs/name/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000553 of size 400 bytes saved in 0 seconds.
2023-11-11 23:37:49,848 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 2 images with txid >= 0
2023-11-11 23:37:49,926 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Starting log segment at 554
2023-11-11 23:37:50,124 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameCache: initialized with 0 entries 0 lookups
2023-11-11 23:37:50,124 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Finished loading FSImage in 1452 msecs
2023-11-11 23:37:50,461 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: RPC server is binding to master:9000
2023-11-11 23:37:50,468 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue queueCapacity: 1000
2023-11-11 23:37:50,483 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 9000
2023-11-11 23:37:50,532 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemState MBean
2023-11-11 23:37:50,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseManager: Number of blocks under construction: 0
2023-11-11 23:37:50,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseManager: Number of blocks under construction: 0
2023-11-11 23:37:50,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: initializing replication queues
2023-11-11 23:37:50,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Leaving safe mode after 2 secs
2023-11-11 23:37:50,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Network topology has 0 racks and 0 datanodes
2023-11-11 23:37:50,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* UnderReplicatedBlocks has 0 blocks
2023-11-11 23:37:50,553 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: Total number of blocks            = 0
2023-11-11 23:37:50,553 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: Number of invalid blocks          = 0
2023-11-11 23:37:50,553 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: Number of under-replicated blocks = 0
2023-11-11 23:37:50,553 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: Number of  over-replicated blocks = 0
2023-11-11 23:37:50,553 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: Number of blocks being written    = 0
2023-11-11 23:37:50,553 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Replication Queue initialization scan for invalid, over- and under-replicated blocks completed in 10 msec
2023-11-11 23:37:50,589 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2023-11-11 23:37:50,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: NameNode RPC up at: master/172.31.46.192:9000
2023-11-11 23:37:50,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Starting services required for active state
2023-11-11 23:37:50,610 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 9000: starting
2023-11-11 23:37:50,616 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.CacheReplicationMonitor: Starting CacheReplicationMonitor with interval 30000 milliseconds
2023-11-11 23:40:52,783 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 2 Total time for transactions(ms): 9 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 2 SyncTimes(ms): 13 
2023-11-11 23:40:52,839 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 4 on 9000, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.addBlock from 172.31.46.192:51584 Call#5 Retry#0
java.io.IOException: File /input/A.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:975)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2036)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2034)
2023-11-11 23:42:53,296 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 4 Total time for transactions(ms): 10 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 4 SyncTimes(ms): 15 
2023-11-11 23:42:53,339 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 6 on 9000, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.addBlock from 172.31.46.192:44734 Call#5 Retry#0
java.io.IOException: File /input/A.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:975)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2036)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2034)
2023-11-11 23:47:57,064 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 6 Total time for transactions(ms): 10 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 6 SyncTimes(ms): 18 
2023-11-11 23:47:57,107 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 6 on 9000, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.addBlock from 172.31.46.192:52554 Call#5 Retry#0
java.io.IOException: File /input/A.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:975)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2036)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2034)
2023-11-11 23:48:25,350 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 5 on 9000, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.addBlock from 172.31.46.192:43190 Call#5 Retry#0
java.io.IOException: File /input/A.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:975)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2036)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2034)
2023-11-11 23:54:02,869 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 10 Total time for transactions(ms): 10 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 10 SyncTimes(ms): 22 
2023-11-11 23:54:02,914 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 6 on 9000, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.addBlock from 172.31.46.192:46218 Call#5 Retry#0
java.io.IOException: File /input/A.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:975)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2036)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2034)
```

Comment: 1) hdfs isn't meant for small text files. Just use S3 2) Why run such an old version of hadoop instead of using EMR? Your datanode isn't healthy. You need to show logs for it. EMR will configure and monitor all that for you

Comment: Actually this part of a assigment and for some reason I have to use older version of Hadoop. I am updating the hdfs-site.xml and adding the latest relvant logs. As I am not used to stack overflow please forgive me if I have done anything wrong.

Comment: Also to add I don't see any erros in resource manager logs and secondary namenode logs, but for some reason I don't see any data node logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised that the logs for datanodes are present in slaves, so I pulled the logs from one of the slaves. I checked the logs and I got this :-

> 2023-11-09 05:41:41,540 WARN
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to
> server: master:9000

So, I changed core-site.xml to this format and resolved the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
                <value>hdfs://Ip-Adrress-Of-Master:9000/</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
                <value>file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.6.5/tmp</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```